# How to bring a Chrome profile with an existing window to the foreground from the command line?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I use Google Chrome with two profiles, each with one window open (and several tabs in each window). I want to be able to bring either profile's window to the foreground by running a command in the terminal. I'm on macOS, but the solution probably works the same on Linux and Windows. I've already checked [all available Chrome switches](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc) but don't see one that does what I want.

---

**Attempt 1:** Chrome brings the window for `Profile 2` to the foreground and opens a new tab for `example.com`. This brings the specified profile to the foreground, without opening a new window, but it opens a new tab; instead I want the last tab used to be selected.

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --profile-directory="Profile 2" "http://example.com/"
```

**Attempt 2:** Chrome opens a *new* window for `Profile 2` and brings it to the foreground. I want to access the already-open window, not open a new one.

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --profile-directory="Profile 2"
```

**Attempt 3:** all Chrome windows are brought to the foreground. The window on top is the last one used, not a specified profile window.

```
open -a 'Google Chrome'
```

**Attempt 4:** all Chrome windows are brought to the foreground. Doesn't ensure `Profile 2` is on top.

```
open -a 'Google Chrome' --args --profile-directory="Profile 2"
```

---

I think attempt 2 is the closest to what I want, except it opens a new window rather than bringing the existing window to the foreground.

Comment: I don't think you can do this from Terminal because it has no GUI scripting. Applescript can do it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173514/applescript-bring-window-to-foreground Alternatively, put one profile on each of two Spaces & key command between them [You'll probably need to repeat this each session, the windows won't stick to two Spaces]

Comment: & why is this tagged linux? macOS is not linux.